# How to know the number of UISwitch that is "On" in a UITableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uiswitch

Is there a way to know the number of UISwitch that is "**ON**" state in a **UITableView**?  I have a multiple UITableViewCell in a **UITableView** -  each has an UISwitch that is "ON" state. I think the code would be more something like:

```
for ([mySwitch on] in tableView){
   code goes here.....
}
```

Comment: is your tableview using static cells or dynamic cells? and the answers will be very different.

Comment: Im using dynamic cells.

Comment: still needed some help here

Comment: see my answer, hope it will help

Comment: can you add the link - Im pretty lost.

Comment: where is the link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you know, ios developing is using the MVC pattern, the content you display in a view or the states of UI widgets should binding with your view models, as in your case, you can create a view model like `SwichViewModel` which has a BOOL property `isSwitchOn`, when you load your table view, you turn on/off the switch base on its view model's `isSwitchOn` property, and the count of turned on switches is the count of the view models which `isSwitchOn` is YES. Below is my example code:

```
//create the view model
@interface SwitchViewModel : NSObject

@property (assign, nonatomic) BOOL isSwitchOn;

@end

@interface TableViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *switchViewModels;

@end

@implementation TableViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.switchViewModels = [self getData]; // you need to implement the getData method
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return self.switchViewModels.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    SwitchViewModel *model = self.switchViewModels[indexPath.row];
    SwitchTVCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellID" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.switcher.on = model.isSwitchOn;
    return cell;
}

- (NSInteger)getCountOfSwitchsOn{
    NSArray *switchsOn = [self.switchViewModels filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"isSwitchOn == %@", @(YES)]];
    return switchsOn.count;
}

@end
```

Comment: hi MudOnTire thanks its working - though i cannot adjust the Switch to be "off" even i already placed a static value NO on it.

Comment: MyBookingObjects *booking1 = [[MyBookingObjects alloc]initWithId:@"1" startDateTime:@"Start Date" endDateTime:@"End Date" sitterAvailability:@"2" streetAddress:@"SomeStreet" suburb:@"SomeSuburd" postalCode:@"SomePostalCode" contactNumber:@"SomeContactNumber" nameOfChild:@"No saved child yet." childYrsOld:nil addInfo:@"Clean the dishes" profileImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"boy_unselected"] isSwitchOn:@(NO)];

Comment: what is the right entry isSwitchOn:[nsnumber numberWith Bool:0]; or isSwitchOn:@(NO)

Comment: The two syntax are equivalent. If you want to make the switches interactive, use delegation.

Answer (score 2):

You have to maintain mutable array ( NSMutableArray ) in accordance of UISwitch, when switch goes on / off you have to maintain that value ( flag ) in mutable array.

When you reload UITableView make all array items with ON flag. when you change your switch to off, then fire a method of switch and as per indexpath.row you have to OFF flag at objectAtIndex in array.

So that array will provide you all values of no of switches are on or off.